# How can I print output with a string containing a field from a file?

Tags: awk

Say I'm looking for a line with the word "yellow" in it from a file called "filename". I then want the output to say "The colour of the shirt is yellow"

Say the line I've pulled out of the file "filename" looks like this:

```
blue green orange black purple white yellow pink
```

I'm thinking something like this but I know it’s not right:

```
cat filename | grep yellow | awk '{print $7; echo "The colour of the shirt is {$7}}
```

Comment: Well, this looks like you could just do `echo "The colour of the shirt is yellow"` without using `awk` or the input file at all, since there's really no decision made here. Or at least, I'm not sure why it's exactly "yellow" you're looking for, or what should be done if "yellow" is not listed.

Comment: Or was the question more about how to stick the contents of some field in the output of awk along with a fixed string?

Comment: Sorry its a bad example. Its work related so I don't really want to say too much. Basically, I got as far as an output of a line after using grep. I then want to feed the 7th field of that line and say "The colour of the shirt is "{the output of the 7th field}"

Comment: Writing a good question is hard, particularly if you're translating an internal problem. You have two answers for "looking for a line with the word yellow", when you might actually want "looking for a line (that matches some other criteria) and print the 7th word". If you can elaborate on that process in a new question, you may get answers that are better suited to your actual problem.

Comment: Good point Jeff. I'll try to be more specific next time round. Lesson learned! Cheers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically, I got as far as an output of a line after using grep. I then want to feed the 7th field of that line and say "The colour of the shirt is "{the output of the 7th field}"

Ok, this makes more sense to me.

To print the seventh field, along with a string, use

```
awk '{ printf "The color is %s\n", $7 }'
```

or

```
awk '{ print "The color is " $7 }'
```

(note that there's no comma or plus or anything between the quoted string and `$7`, strings are concatenated in awk by just writing them next to each other.)

You can skip the `grep` too and do the equivalent inside `awk`:

```
awk '/some regex/ { printf "the seventh field is %s\n", $7 }'
```

awk accepts mostly the same regexes as `grep -E`. ("mostly", since I can't remember if there are some minor differences.) But you can also point the pattern match to just a particular field:

```
awk '$3 ~ /regex for field three/ { printf "the seventh field is %s\n", $7 }'
```

Of course it processes all matching lines. Silly example:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^j/ { printf "the shirt of %s is %s\n", $1, $2 } ' < shirts
the shirt of jimmy is blue
the shirt of joe is red
```

Comment: Thank you! This is it. My apologies to all for the poor question. I'll try to be more exact the next time round.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk ‘/yellow/ { print “The colour of the shirt is yellow” }’ < filename
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it all in `awk` [as Jeff showed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420916/116858), or you could it quite easily in the shell instead:

```
if grep -qF 'yellow' "filename"; then
    echo 'The colour of the shirt is yellow'
fi
```

Here, `-q` stops `grep` from outputting anything (we're only interested in the exit status of `grep`) and `-F` tells `grep` that we are searching with a "fixed string" (not a regular expression).

---

If you instead had a file whose contents was

```
[some unrelated data here]
shirt colour: yellow
[some unrelated shirt data here]
```

Then you could use

```
awk '/^shirt colour:/ { print "The colour of the shirt is", $NF }' filename
```

... to output a message using the word in last field (`$NF`) of the line that matches the given regular expression.

Alternatively,

```
awk '/^shirt colour:/ { printf("The colour of the shirt is %s\n", $NF) }' filename
```

In the last two examples, you could also use `$3` ("the third whitespace-separated field") in place of `$NF` ("the last such field").